# How to sort a list of tuples based on the 2nd value without hardcoding it

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples.

```
[('first_title', 'first_content','notes'),('second_title','second_content','Lists'), ('third_title', 'third_content','Books'), ('fourth_title', 'fourth_content','Chores')
```

and I want to get each tuple in the code and place them in a list where that list has only the tuples that have the same 2nd value (starting at 0) but without hardcoding what the second value or the length of the list.So the result would look like...

```
notes = [('first_title, 'first_content, 'notes')]
Lists = [('second_title, 'second_content, 'Lists')]
Books = [('third_title, 'third_content, 'Books')]
Chores = [('fourth_title, 'fourth_content, 'Chores')]
```

so I can't really do...

```
if x[2] == 'Lists'
```

because it's hardcoded.

If there was another tuple that had the 2nd element (starting at 0) equal to `'Books'` then it would be in the `Books` list for example.

Comment: If there was another tuple that had the 2nd element (starting at 0) = to 'Books' then it would be in the books list for example

Comment: You've suggested that you want the results in variables named `notes`, `Lists` etc. whose names match the 3rd value in a tuple. Is that literally what you want or would having the results in a dict keyed off the value `notes`, `Lists` etc. suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to create a dictionary of lists where the third value in each tuple is used as key.

You can use a `defaultdict` to create a new list automatically when a key is inserted for the first time:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

for item in list_of_tuples:
    key = item[2]
    result[key].append(item)
```

Now you can use `result['notes']`, `result['Lists']`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for `filter`?

This would allow you to reuse some of the code like this (throw in a selector if you want to be even more flexible but not required):

```
inp = [('first_title', 'first_content','notes'),('second_title','second_content','Lists'), ('third_title', 'third_content','Books'), ('fourth_title', 'fourth_content','Chores')]

def get_by(category, l, selector=lambda x: x[2]):
    return filter(l, lambda x: selector(x) == category)
```

I can then get the categories:

```
get_by('Books', inp)
```

Or I can change the selector and filter on some other criteria:

```
get_by('first_title', inp, selector=lambda x: x[0])
```